Two possible serious mistakes on the web "graphclasses"
A bipartite graph is chordal bipartite if each cycle of length at least 6 has a chord.
The website graphclasses describes it as follows

Let $G=(X, Y, E)$ be a bipartite graph. An edge $(x, y)$ is called
bisimplicial if $N(x) \cup N(y)$ induces a complete bipartite graph in
$G$.Let $\left(e_1, \ldots, e_m\right)$ be an ordering of the edges of
$G$. Let $G_0=G$ and $G_i=G_{i-1} \backslash e_i\left(G_i\right.$ is
obtained from $G_{i-1}$ by removing the edge $e_i$ but not its
endvertices). The ordering $\left(e_1, \ldots, e_m\right)$ is a
perfect edgewithout-vertex elimination ordering if $e_i$ is
bisimplicial in $G_{i-1}$ for all $1 \leq i \leq m$.

It asserts the following:
Claim 1. A bipartite graph is chordal bipartite if it admits a perfect edge-without-vertex elimination ordering.
The term 'remove edge $e_i$' here seems to cause ambiguity. According to the article [1] below, it is necessary to delete edge $e_i$ and all edges adjacent with $e_i$.
[1] Golumbic M C, Goss C F. Perfect elimination and chordal bipartite graphs[J]. Journal of Graph Theory, 1978, 2(2): 155-163.
More interestingly, in [1], Theorem 4 states that every chordal bipartite graph is a perfect elimination bipartite graph. It also mentions that the converse is not true. So
I believe Claim 1 from the web is also false.
I'm not sure if I misunderstood.

What is your question?

My question is that I feel there are two serious mistakes on this website. The first one is the description of the elimination sequence, and the second one is a statement (Claim 1). I want to make sure if I have misunderstood something.

The website's contact page has a form for reporting errors. Why not just let them decide if you've misunderstood something?

Thanks. I have already contacted them via email.
